# java Error: Could not find or load main class TestBus

Tags: java

```
 public class Sample2 {

    int a=11;
 int b = 22;
}
class DemoBus extends Sample2 {
    int a=25;
    int b=26;
    void m1(){
    System.out.println("demo class m2");
    }
}
class TestBus extends DemoBus
{
    int d=65;
    int e = 78;
    void m2(){
        System.out.println("sample class m2");
    }
    void m3(){
        System.out.println("sample class m3");
    }
void show()
{
    int a=45;
    int c=90;
    TestBus t = new TestBus();
    System.out.println(t.a);
    System.out.println(super.a);
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(this.a);
    System.out.println(d);
    System.out.println(a);
    m1();
    m2();
m3();

}
public static void main(String ar[])
{
    TestBus s = new TestBus();
    s.show();
}
}
```

I tried to execute it but it is not executing. I tried with 'public' kept for TestBus, still it's showing error. I also
tried in cmd  with TestBus then the code executed and output is displayed 
but in ide its showing error.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: This code runs for me.I can's see the problem.

Comment: hi i am using Eclipse and its showing output as  Error: Could not find or load main class TestBus

Answer (score -1):

You should put main method in the **public class** in your case  **Sample2** and it should work!
 I have tried it in NetBeans and it works.

The problem whith your code is that your `.java` file is named **Sample2** and when your program is executed by JRE, it does not find your *main* method inside your source files (.java files) even if your method is static.